# android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, actionbarsherlock

please help me 
i face this problem and i cant solve it , i use in my main activity (extends)SherlockFragmentActivity 
each Fragment extends SherlockFragment

```
 package com.Schoolreporting.androidApp.adapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.Schoolreporting.androidApp.R;
    import com.Schoolreporting.androidApp.model.NavDrawerItem;


    public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

        public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
            this.context = context;
            this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return navDrawerItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {       
            return navDrawerItems.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
// here its crash 
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            }

            ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

            imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
            txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

            // displaying count
            // check whether it set visible or not
            if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
                txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
            }else{
                // hide the counter view
                txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

thats my main activity

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my error log

```
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at com.Schoolreporting.androidApp.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter.getView(NavDrawerListAdapter.java:48)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2603)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1327)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1651)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2426)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:825)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1694)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14905)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2213)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2027)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1237)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5162)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    ... 46 more
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01001f a=3}
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2963)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:343)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:903)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:838)
    07-02 10:57:47.740: E/AndroidRuntime(11411):    ... 49 more
```

any suggestion

Comment: the problem is related to   android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"

Comment: why you say that i remove it and no thing change

Comment: I mean, if you take a look to the stacktrace you have `Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
imgIcon.setImageDrawable(convertView.getResources().getDrawable(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon()));
```

Instead of

```
imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
```